# Django Rest Framework and Google Cloud SQL Intermittent Server Errors

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-sql

I'm running a Django Rest Framework app on Ubuntu 14.04.3 with Nginx 1.4.6, with a Google Cloud SQL backend. I'm using Django 1.7 and Django Rest Framework 3.1.2.

Both the site and the Google Cloud SQL connection are running over SSL.

What I'm running into is that about one in every 75-100 requests returns a 500 error. It's very intermittent. If, for example, a request to get the values for a dropdown list in a popup control fails once, if I close and re-open the popup it will work the second time.

It affects calls to random endpoints - I haven't been able to detect a pattern.

The Django error log shows:

```
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180353/django-project-looking-for-attribute-session-cache) I've verified that the database does have a django_session table and `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` is in my `settings.py` file.

At the bottom of the error log details, I see:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')
```

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023379/intermittent-ssl-error-on-google-cloud-sql-with-django), but it's unclear to me if this is the same thing. My setup is much more vanilla than what's described there (no load balancing, no celery) and there doesn't appear to be an official issue opened up by the Google Cloud SQL team on this issue (I haven't been able to find it, anyway).

The full stack trace for one of the errors:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/ref/contact-types/ 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 170, in _get_session
 return self._session_cache 
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache' 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection 
 self.connect() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect 
 self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 471, in get_new_connection 
 conn = Database.connect(**conn_params) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 
81, in Connect 
 return Connection(*args, **kwargs) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", 
line 204, in __init__ 
 super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) 
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number') 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 87, in get_response 
 response = middleware_method(request) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 34, in process_request 
 if user and hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash'): 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", 
line 224, in inner 
 self._setup() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", 
line 357, in _setup 
 self._wrapped = self._setupfunc() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 23, in <lambda> 
 request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request)) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 11, in get_user 
 request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 151, in get_user 
 user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY] 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 49, in __getitem__ 
 return self._session[key] 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 175, in _get_session 
 self._session_cache = self.load() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 21, in load 
 expire_date__gt=timezone.now() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method 
 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get 
 num = len(clone) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__ 
 num = len(clone) 
 self._fetch_all() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all 
 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator()) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator 
 for row in compiler.results_iter(): 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_ 
iter 
 for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI): 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 784, in execute_ 
sql 
 cursor = self.connection.cursor() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 167, in cursor 
 cursor = utils.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor 
 self.ensure_connection() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_con 
nection 
 self.connect() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, 
in __exit__ 
 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 
549, in reraise 
 raise value.with_traceback(tb) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_con 
nection 
 self.connect() 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect 
 self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 471, in get_new_ 
connection 
 conn = Database.connect(**conn_params) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 
81, in Connect 
 return Connection(*args, **kwargs) 
 File "/home/foo/bar/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", 
line 204, in __init__ 
 super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')
```

Comment: Hello, this appears to be the same case as the question you linked. It is being resolved by the Google Cloud SQL team, really sorry for the problems this may have caused you.

Comment: See official post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/eZzVkspi1oY